# If someone has children from a non-Jewish woman, should he try to convert the kids?

Tags: gentiles, conversion-to-judaism

Suppose a man has children from a non-Jewish woman, though of course the marriage was forbidden. Should he try to convert the kids? Please provide arguments based on Judaism, or Jewish sources that indicate one way or the other, not your personal opinion. Obviously, the practical decision will depend on the individuals circumstances; I'm looking for generalities even if they may not apply in all cases.

Comment: Why might you think he should?

Comment: It depends on so many parameters: whether the person remains married, how his wife feels about it, the age of the kids, whether the father is observant, etc. This is not a good place to ask about this and is best discussed with a rabbi who knows the family

Comment: Why WAS IT DELETED? Even if his biological kids convert they don't [officially] relate to him in any way - no monetary obligations, no inheritance, no Kibud Av etc. They can marry their other biological sisters and brothers that convert [theoretically].

Comment: Not a precise reason why he should, but I remember hearing in yeshiva (about a classmate who found out that his mother was not Jewish, only his father, and then left the yeshiva and yidishkite) that one should in these cases.